# How to write a like query in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP string with a like query - something like this:

```
$select = "select category_id, category_name from categories where category_name like %"'.$category.'"%;
```

But I am pretty sure this is totally wrong, and I am getting confused in the million quotes :)

Whats the right way to put this query together?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's just:

```
$select = "select category_id, category_name from categories
           where category_name like '%$category%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for "best practices", you should look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) using the [`mysqli` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php). That being said,

1. Your quotes are backwards around the `$category` variable (it's `"'`, it should be `'"`)
2. The `%`'s in your statement should be inside the quotes (`'`), not outside them

Answer (score 2):

You want the % wildcards in the string, not outside it.

Also, If you want to evaluate the php variable in the string, you should brace the variable.

```
" select category_id, category_name from categories where category_name like '%{$category}%' "
```

or concatenate it

```
" select category_id, category_name from categories where category_name like '%" . $category . "%' "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use positional parameters. Not sure what database server you're using, but say you're using the PDO layer, then have a look at [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to do it a different way but to answer the question, if you use double quotes you not need to concatenate the variable with the dot

```
$select = "select category_id, category_name from categories where category_name like '%{$category}%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You messed up the quotes

```
"select [...] like '%".$category."%'";
```

That will become

```
select [...] like '%something%'
```

But you should use query parameters, to avoid sql injections

Answer (score 1):

This will be relatively functional:

```
$select = "select category_id, category_name from categories where category_name like '%"
     .mysql_real_escape_string($category)."%'";
```

However, you'll probably want to additionally escape characters that have special meaning inside of a `LIKE`, including `%`

Note also that mysql will not be able to use an index to optimize this query, meaning it won't perform on large databases.  You may wish to investigate myISAM fulltext indexes for text search over a large dataset.